# How to find the interval of convergence for $\frac{8x^{n}}{9^{n+1}}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I want to find the interval of convergence for $$\frac{8x^{n}}{9^{n+1}}.$$ I've tried everything and just can't seem to find it. I looked up a calculator and it said $(-9, 9)$, but I don't understand why it wouldn't be $[-9,9)$.

Comment: -9 would render "oscillating" result.

Comment: @JihyungKang Could you please further explain that to me?

Comment: If $x=-9$, the expression simplifies to $\left(-\frac89\right)^n$, which alternates between $-\frac89$ and $\frac89$ (i.e. divergent).

Comment: @PatrickYen, just to be clear, are you asking about the convergence of the *sequence* $a_n=8x^n/9^{n+1}$, or are you really interested in the *power series* $\sum_{n=0}^\infty8x^n/9^{n+1}$? (The phrase "interval of convergence" is more commonly used for power series than for sequences.)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x=-9$. Then

$$\frac{8x^n}{9^{n+1}} = \frac{8(-9)^n}{9^{n+1}} = \frac{8(-1)^n9^n}{9^{n+1}}= \frac 8 9 \cdot (-1)^n$$

This obviously doesn't converge.